# Sending File from angular 5 to java backend

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm beginner for the Angular, I succeed to upload File to angular5 and now I have trouble with sending it (pdf) from angular to backend. I tried to find some tutorials or doc, but it didn't work. So I would appreciate help in finding mistake.

Service in angular:

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({  
        'Content-Type':'application/pdf; charset=utf-8',    
      })
    };
return this.http.post("api/magazines/add", file, httpOptions);


Controller - backend:
@RequestMapping(value="/add",method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/pdf")
    private ResponseEntity<String> addMagazine(@RequestBody File file) {
...
}
```

The error is:

```
error: {timestamp: "2019-02-06T17:46:26.998+0000", status: 415, error: "Unsupported Media Type", message: "Content type 'application/pdf;charset=utf-8' not supported" ...}
```

Comment: Your content type should probably be `multipart/form-data` for a file upload.

Comment: @TheHeadRush It works! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Then please mark the answer/comment as "useful" for a reward.

Comment: @chris01 And how to do that?

Comment: There is a symbol "arrow up" left of every comment and answer. Hover the mouse over it and you will see its meaning.

Comment: @chris01 If I'm right, I can't do it unless I have 15 rep, which I don't.